# asp.net string to listviewitem

Tags: asp.net, listview, listviewitem, ascx

I have a control (ascx) that has an itemtemplate for inserted service locations. What I am trying to do is OnDataBound event have an item already added upon the listview showing. The listview is for city and state. I have been trying to use the ListViewItemInsertArgs, but the signature is wrong. Been trying to figure this out for days..

```
protected void lvServiceLocations_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    ListView lv = sender as ListView;

    var lvi = new ListViewDataItem(0, 0);
    lvi.DataItem = da_User_Data.Select_Applicant_Specific_Results(userProfileId, dlControlId); //this returns a string
    lv.Items.Insert(0, lvi);
}
    <asp:ListView ID="lvServiceLocations" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsServiceLocations" DataKeyNames="user_service_location_id" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem"
     OnItemInserting="lvServiceLocations_ItemInserting"
     OnDataBound="lvServiceLocations_DataBound">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table class="location-selection-table ui-widget-content">
                <tr><th colspan="4" class="ui-widget-header">Locations</th></tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="location-selection-item-row">
                <td class="location-selection-actions"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Remove" CommandName="Delete" /></td>
                <td><%# Eval("selected_state") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("selected_county") %></td>
                <td class="location-selection-actions"></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataBound` event will only occur if you call the `DataBind` method, and it will only occur once either `Page.DataBind` or `Ctrl.DataBind` is called but in any case it is not in this method where you have to insert the new item but instead you have to add it to the Source of the data set in the datasource and then you reset the control with a DataBind method call.

So you have to insert the new item into the source associated with `sdsServiceLocations` and not directly into the control

Comment: That would put the data into the database I believe, which IS something I want to do. However, I wanted a UI representation of the county & state I pretty much hardcoded in. So when the control shows up its already there and they can choose additional county & state, then I'd be inserting to DB.

Comment: I'm trying to add a default or static item into the itemtemplate within the layouttemplate